# Memory leak using variable len feature in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

We have tensorflow application in which we feed data via queues in batched of 250.
After moving to use VarLenFeature (instead of FixedLenFeature) we started to have memory leak during training where the memory was constantly increasing. We are training our models using GPU machines.

This is the decode code:

```
@staticmethod
def decode(serialized_example):
    features = tf.parse_example(
        serialized_example,
        # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
        features={
            # target_features
            RECS: tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
            CLICK: tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32)
        })
    return features
```

then we convert the sparse to dense using:

```
tf.identity(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(tensor), name=key)
```

and then we loop over with batched over tensorflow queues

This is the create queue code:

```
@staticmethod
def create_queue(tensors, capacity, shuffle=False, min_after_dequeue=None, seed=None,
                 enqueue_many=False, shapes=None, shared_name=None, name=None):
    tensor_list = _as_tensor_list(tensors)
    with ops.name_scope(name, "shuffle_batch_queue", list(tensor_list)):
        tensor_list = _validate(tensor_list)

        tensor_list, sparse_info = _store_sparse_tensors(
            tensor_list, enqueue_many, tf.constant(True))
        map_op = [x.map_op for x in sparse_info]
        types = _dtypes([tensor_list])
        shapes = _shapes([tensor_list], shapes, enqueue_many)

        queue = data_flow_ops.RandomShuffleQueue(
            capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, seed=seed,
            dtypes=types, shapes=shapes, shared_name=shared_name)

    return queue, sparse_info, map_op
```

And the enqueue operation is:

```
@staticmethod
def enqueue(queue, tensors, num_threads, enqueue_many=False, name=None, map_op = None):
    tensor_list = _as_tensor_list(tensors)
    with ops.name_scope(name, "shuffle_batch_equeue", list(tensor_list)):
        tensor_list = _validate(tensor_list)
        tensor_list, sparse_info = _store_sparse_tensors(
            tensor_list, enqueue_many, tf.constant(True), map_op)
        _enqueue(queue, tensor_list, num_threads, enqueue_many, tf.constant(True))
    return queue, sparse_info
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a minimal example?  e.g., do you continue to have the memory leak if you just call the example parsing over and over again via multiple session.run calls, and not have any queues?

The reason I ask is that the `_store_sparse_tensors` is hidden to that file for a reason; if you misuse it, you **will** hit a memory leak.  Thus all callers of this function must be very careful to use it correctly.  For every sparse tensor stored via `_store_sparse_tensors`, that same tensor **must** be restored via `_restore_sparse_tensors`.  If it is not, you will leak memory.

I'm considering a `DT_VARIANT` storage format to replace this wrapper, but for now I'd recommend against using these functions yourself.  Instead, you can probably do what you want using the new `tf.contrib.data` (soon to be `tf.data`) libraries!

Comment: Before the use of VarLenFeature there was no memory leak. The only change that i didn't pass map_op in the enqueue method  i.e.:  tensor_list, sparse_info = _store_sparse_tensors(tensor_list, enqueue_many, tf.constant(True))

Comment: Right.  Can you tell me if you have a memory leak if you are just parsing the VarLenFeature -- not using _store_sparse_tensors?

Comment: Not using _store_sparse_tensors or using it without map_op from the previous call is not working. I think i'll try your suggestion to use tf.contrib.data.  Do you know if it supports multithreaded processing? i have multiple hdfs files with tfrecords which i want to feed in parallel

Comment: yes, there are arguments to the .map function to enable parallelism.  see also the interleave and prefetch methods in the tf nightlies

Comment: I tried tf.contrib.data but it doesn't support SpaeseTesors at least the TFRecordDataset the map operation fails with exception "TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor " do you know if it should work?

Comment: At present, `tf.SparseTensor` does not work in `Dataset.map()`. To use a sparse tensor `st`, you'll need to unpack it into a tuple of tensors `(st.indices, st.values, st.dense_shape)`. (We're working on making this transparent!)

Comment: @mrry Also tried FixedLenSequenceFeature   F_CLICKS: tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32, allow_missing=True, default_value=0),  but it gives me exception of InternalError (see above for traceback): HandleElementToSlice Cannot copy slice: number of elements does not match.  Shapes are: [element]: [2], [parent slice]: [7]
E         [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[?], [?], [?,26], [?,?], [?]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OneShotIterator)]]

Comment: Finally did you solve it? I have exactly the same issue in tf 1.8